# Get selected value from react bootstrap AsyncTypeHead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, typehead

I am using react bootstrap `AsyncTypeHead`. I type keywords and it suggests values from the backend, then I click one of the suggestions and try to get the value selected, but it seems event does not exist. It throws all kind of errors. What could be the issue? I am trying to do it through `onChange` attribute with `event.target.value`:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
  filterBy={filterBy}
  id="async-example"
  isLoading={isLoading}
  labelKey="login"
  minLength={3}
  onSearch={handleSearch}
  onChange={ (event) => setCitiesSend([...citiesSend, event.target.value])}
```

If instead `event.target.value` I put `alert('test')` it throws alert multiple times. It seems to be changing on each typed letter.

Full example: [React Bootstrap Typeahead - Asynchronous Searching](https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` function returns a value.
So, your code will be.

```
<AsyncTypeahead
   filterBy={filterBy}
   id="async-example"
   isLoading={isLoading}
   labelKey="login"
   minLength={3}
   onSearch={handleSearch}
   onChange={ (value) => setCitiesSend((previous) =>[...previous, ...value])}
/>
```